# Match the same expression on a single String and convert to List

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have been working on this for a while and i guess i am getting ahead of myself here. For reasons i am getting the output you get when you toString a Java object and i am trying to serialize it back to an object. If it was a single object it would be easy but i have a list and i want to capture every single one inside the list.

So the object

> List(AcquireRequest(x2,x3,1466008848103,5,5,5,whatever,List(ResourceAllocation(allocation,5),
>   ResourceAllocation(Lolication,25))),
>   AcquireRequest(x2,x3,1466008848103,5,5,5,whatever,List(ResourceAllocation(allocation,5),
>   ResourceAllocation(Lolication,25))),
>   AcquireRequest(x2,x3,1466008848103,5,5,5,whatever,List(ResourceAllocation(allocation,5),
>   ResourceAllocation(Lolication,555))))

This is a list of objects AcquireRequest that inside have several fields strings and/or numbers and a List of Another objects. All i want is to match the AcquireRequest strings individually so i would get as a result a List(String) each one with an AcquireRequest.

I tried pattern matching, using java matcher and many more.

Some regex attempts by myself:

> (AcquireRequest(.*(?=,\s).*(?=,)\d*(?=,)\d*(?=,)\d*(?=,)\d*(?=,).*?(?=,).*(?=)))(?=,|))
>
> AcquireRequest((.*),(.*),(\d*),(\d*),(\d*),(\d*),(.*?),(.*))
>
> AcquireRequest((.+))

The first one is my current attempt but it is still matching everything except the outside List( ). I figured i just needed a lookahead because after a AcquireRequest expression i either get a ", " which means another element is coming or a ) which means it is the last.

Thank you for the help !

Comment: I'd recommend not using regex for this. Moreover, I'd recommend using industry-standard serialization formats (binary, JSON, XML), instead of Java `String` representation of objects, which aren't designed for serialization.

Comment: Yeah i completely agree with you, i assumed this was a simple solution but understood that it was not after a while. I mean, i have 90% of the marshelling/unmarshelling using simple pattern matching but this one case just does not work with Regex. I will move to a json lib but i am one of those people that can't let a problem go and i have lost hours on this one. I need to understand if this is possible to do with regex anyway

Comment: This should be possible with a lookahead but it is not working how i want it to.

Comment: Good that you are moving to JSON. There *might* be a way with regex, but if any, it's going to be long (read, unreadable, unmaintainable) and fragile. I'd say "let it go", you already lost hours as you state, don't lose more!

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be one regex? How about something like this:

```
   string
     .replaceAll("""\w+?\(|\)+""", "")
     .split(",\\s*")
     .grouped(11)
```

This should work as long as the string values on your data do not contain parentheses or commas. But if they do, then you are screwed anyway, there is no regex solution, you need a real syntax parser.

In response to the last comment (about inner lists being variable size).
I never actually meant to provide you with a complete solution (you may have better lack on freelancer.com getting people to write code to your exact specifications), just wanted to kinda point you in the right direction. But, ok, how about this:

```
  string
    .split("""\({2,},?\s*""")
    .map { _.replaceAll("""\w+?\(|\)+""", "").split(",\\s*") }
```

Comment: It does not have to be one. However, i want to isolate the AcquireRequest structures. What i got when i run your code was a list of each individual field from all structures, for a total of 33 elements, when all i need is 3. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Yeah. i almost got it now. The only thing left is that the replace and split is leaving the fields with an empty space before the string. Just have to trim that and good to go

Comment: Edited again to remove spaces.

Comment: Btw, i noticed a problem that the grouped(11) works if the ResourceAllocation list has exactly 2 elements just like it has now. But if it has more than 2 elements the group amount has to change :/